# Elasticsearch scoring

Tags: elasticsearch, cosine-similarity

I'm using elasticsearch to find similar documents to a given document using the "more like this" query.

Is there an easy way to get the elasticsearch scoring between 0 and 1 (using cosine similarity) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into the [Function Score functionality of Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html), more specifically the `script_score` and `field_value_factor` functions. This will allow you to take the score from default scoring (`_score`) and enhance or replace it in other ways. It really depends on what sort of boosting or transformation you'd like. The default scoring model takes into account the [Vector model](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#vector-space-model) but other things as well .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible to retrieve directly.

But perhaps this workaround would make sense?

Elasticsearch always bring back `max_score` in `hits` document.

You can potentially divide your document `_score` by `max_score`. Report with highest value will score as 1, documents, that are not so like given one, will score less.

Answer (score 0):

The Elasticsearch uses the Boolean model to find matching documents, and a formula called the practical scoring function to calculate relevance. This formula borrows concepts from term frequency/inverse document frequency and the vector space model but adds more-modern features like a coordination factor, field length normalization, and term or query clause boosting.